# Python Regex fetch string correctly but still has AttributeError

Tags: python, regex

I want to fetch ftp account information form vsftp log by regex.
All of our accounts were named by user plus number such as user01, user02, user03.

```
Tue Sep 12 18:11:20 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 3620 /ftptest.py a _ i r user01 ftp 0 * c
Tue Sep 12 18:12:51 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 4211 /ftptest.py a _ i r user02 ftp 0 * c
Tue Sep 12 18:16:43 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 4322 /ftptest.py a _ i r user03 ftp 0 * c
```

My code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re


with open("/var/log/xferlog") as ftplog:
    for line in ftplog:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        pattern = re.compile(r'user[\d]+')
        match = pattern.search(line)
        print match.group()
```

The result can fetch the user account but also show error message AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

The result:

```
user01
user02
user03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test8.py", line 10, in <module>
    print match.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: That's not the code producing your error. F.x. there is no 11th line.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I delete two line include test pattern and switch the account name but forgot to edit it in my post. I have already corrected it. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pattern.search(line) return None if there is no match to line.
So your code must add a condition on that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
with open("/var/log/xferlog") as ftplog:
    for line in ftplog:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        pattern = re.compile(r'user[\d]+')
        match = pattern.search(line)
        if match:
           print match.group()
```

Regards Youenn.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It worked. The result shows correct account and the error message is gone. But I am very curious why the code has already fetched the string but still show the error message. And the error message disappeared after I added condition statement. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Use a if statement to deal with the case where pattern does not match.

```
...
if match:
    print match.group()  # or anything
```

But note that this will silence all cases where there is no match. If you want to track those (maybe for debug) you can add

```
else:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to get user01, user02, user03 to print based on your sample data and code, but it looks like your regex isn't capturing the values correctly. To help you troubleshoot I'd recommend using using [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to help you walk your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re


with open("sample") as ftplog:
    for line in ftplog:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        pattern = re.compile(r'sparq[\d]+')
        match = pattern.search(line)
        if match is None:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        print match.group()
```

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I delete two line include test pattern and switch the account name but forgot to edit it in my post. I have already corrected it. I am so sorry.